# Advanced AJAX Product Filters with Select2 show select box only below

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-select2

I'm not good at javascript or other languages, that's why I ask someone to help. I am using Wordpress Plugin Advanced AJAX Product Filters for WooCommerce to create custom filters for my Woocommerce website. This plugin use jQuery-based script to make select box (https://github.com/select2/select2).

[It's OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLFa5.png)

[It's not ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NG1T.png)

I understand, that it is because the JS chahging [problem CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szDpz.png)  class from select2-dropdown--above to select2-dropdown--below, that changes position of the block.

Could you help me to change js code to use only select2-dropdown--below veriant. It would be perfect to use this code in wordpress function.php. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you know you can embed images in your question?

Comment: Hello, Mike. I tried to embed images, but it makes as web-links. Sorry((

Comment: You can see my problem on my site: https://auto-mira.ru/shop/

Comment: Please refer to this page https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting help.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I need at least 10 reputation for posting link. But It was realy good advise, next post I will post with images.